# How can a jQuery script be executed during hover without using .on()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know if it is possible to execute the `ParticleGround` jQuery script (or any JavaScript containing a series of functions) on some action event (`mouseover`, `click`, etc) without modifying the file.

For example, when new content is dynamically loaded and the mouse hovers over a new element, I want my JavaScript `ParticleGround` to begin execution without using `.on()` at all in that script.

Is this possible?

Comment: For dynamic content only two possible. One is on() another one is function call. But function call you should bind in the JS. So best is on click.

Comment: Is it possible to use .on() in another script and have that script import or execute the original script though?

Comment: Kindly share your code, what you trying.. If I know surely help you...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

</style>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Divhover(ele){
    console.log(ele);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
var str="";
for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
    str+='<div onmouseenter="Divhover('+i+')" value=""></div>';
}
    $('#mydiv').html(str);
});

</script>
<body>
<div id="mydiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```